# creating new column with second header's string value

Tags: python, string, pandas, header, rename

I have the following dataframe with two headers. I would need to create a new column with the string value of my second header (Industrial dataset)

```
Region           Industrial production                                                          
Italia           5669   
Nord-ovest       1046   
Piemonte         447
```

my final output needs to be:

```
Industrial production   Region  Industrial production
Industrial production   Italia                   5669
Industrial production   Nord-ovest               1046
Industrial production   Piemonte                  447
```

Comment: It's going to say "Industrial production" and nothing else?  Just output "Industrial production" as the column's value.  You already know how to do that.

Comment: You need to rename one of the industrial production columns

Comment: or `df.insert(0, 'Type', 'Industrial Production', allow_duplicates=True)` if not index.

Comment: As a comment: I am uploading multiple files that have a weird data organization - one of the main identifying info [industrial production] is in the second header rather than being a column on its own. Other files won't have "industrial production, but other identifying info such as population or GDP. That is why I cannot simply rename it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas you cannot have two columns with the exact same name, if you try to create another column named `Industrial production` it will overwrite the existent one:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
       Region  Industrial production
0      Italia                   5669
1  Nord-ovest                   1046
2    Piemonte                    447

In [3]: second = df.columns[1]

In [4]: second
Out[4]: 'Industrial production'

In [5]: df[second] = second

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
       Region  Industrial production
0      Italia  Industrial production
1  Nord-ovest  Industrial production
2    Piemonte  Industrial production
```

You need to give this new column a different name, for example `Industrial production2`. Then you can create it as follows:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
       Region  Industrial production
0      Italia                   5669
1  Nord-ovest                   1046
2    Piemonte                    447

In [3]: second = df.columns[1]

In [3]: df[second + "2" ] = second

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
       Region  Industrial production Industrial production2
0      Italia                   5669  Industrial production
1  Nord-ovest                   1046  Industrial production
2    Piemonte                    447  Industrial production
```

---

As an alternative, you can use [df.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), as follows:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
       Region  Industrial production
0      Italia                   5669
1  Nord-ovest                   1046
2    Piemonte                    447

In [4]: df = df.assign(**{df.columns[1] + "2": df.columns[1]})

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
       Region  Industrial production Industrial production2
0      Italia                   5669  Industrial production
1  Nord-ovest                   1046  Industrial production
2    Piemonte                    447  Industrial production
```

Comment: How do I move Industrial production2 to the first column of the dataframe? Reindexing?

Comment: @FilippoSebastio The easiest way is this `df = df[["Industrial production2", "Region", "Industrial production"]]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it as an index then you can use:

df.set_index([list(df.columns.values)[1]], inplace=True).

This will take the second column, or you can directly write the name of second column header. Code will be some what close to this. 
Hope This helps